# How can I set my variable in C++ to 0 and prevent it from getting random?

Tags: c++, variables, random, int

I am a beginner in programming. I was doing some simple applications. I was already done with my programme when I realised that my variable is getting random, even if I set it to 0. I was trying to figure it out why. My goal is to add 1 to the "cor" variable when the answer is matching the random generated number, the "else" section is working as it has to be. Maybe someone more experienced can help me.

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int number;
int ynumber[5];
int cor = 0;
int falsed = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to our lottery!" << endl; 

    cout << "We start in ..." << endl;
    Sleep(2000);


    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << i << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    system("cls");
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Type your " << i+1 << " number below" << endl;
        cin >> ynumber[i];

        number = rand() % 50 + 1;
        cout << "The picked number is: " << number << endl;
        Sleep(1000);

        if (ynumber[i] == number)
        {
            cout << "Same same!" << endl;
            cor = cor + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Hope for better luck next time ;)" << endl;
            falsed = falsed + 1; 
        }
    }

    system("cls");

    cout << "Thank you for participating!" << endl << "Correct picked numbers: " << cor << endl << "Wrong picked numbers: " << falsed << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: How many elements is there in the array `ynumber`? How many elements do you write to in the loop?

Comment: ***I realised that my variable is getting random*** Which variable?

Comment: Better change `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` since you have `int ynumber[5];`

Comment: Also, don't use global variables, define the variables as close as possible to the place where they are being used.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: By the way, with the current code you don't actually need the array at all. A simple variable `int ynumber;` would be enough. That would of course also solve the [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) you have by going out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Rather than asking others to debug your program it's going to be more productive to try to learn how to debug.

Comment: "*my variable is getting random, even if I set it to 0*" - sounds like a classic **buffer overflow** to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int ynumber[5];
> ```

The length of your array is 5

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
> {
> //...
>      cin >> ynumber[i];
> ```

You loop over the indices 0,1,2,3,4,5. Use your fingers to count the number of indices that you use. You'll notice that you access the array at 6 different fingers. 6 is more than 5. As such, we can conclude that you're accessing the array out of bounds. The consequence is that behaviour of your program is undefined.

Solution: Do not access an array out of bounds. The last index of array of length `n` is `n - 1`.

More generally: Don't rely on magic numbers. In this case, you could use instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::size(ynumber); i++)
```

Comment: Thank you I forgot about it when I was changing the number in the array ;).

Comment: @MateuszDettlaff Using `std::size` neatly avoids *that* problem :)